# XML WriteAttributeString error

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

When I write this entry here:

```
<XmlRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:nsSBAK" xsi:schemaLocation ="urn:nsSBAK SBAK.xsd">
```

with this code:

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("XmlRoot");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", null, null, "urn:nsSBAK");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("schemaLocation", null, "urn:nsSBAK SBAK.xsd");
```

I get debug error:

> The prefix '' cannot be redefined
>   from '' to 'urn:nsSBAK' within the
>   same start element tag.

Can you help me ?

Comment: which line are you getting the error on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the namespace of the element on the WriteStartElement itself.
Also noticed you did not add the namespace to your schemaLocation. wich you dit in your desired result. Also added that for you in my example:

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("XmlRoot", "urn:nsSBAK");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "urn:nsSBAK SBAK.xsd");
```