# C# Write xmlns before other attributes with XMLWriter

Tags: c#, xml

This is the code to make the startelement of the XML:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("LIEFERUNG-AUSWI", "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01");      
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "aw", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "bbk", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01                                       BbkXmwAuswi_2013.xsd");
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "version", null, "1.0");
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "erstellzeit", null, Dat_DatZeit);
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "stufe", null, "Produktion");
```

The output is this:

```
<LIEFERUNG-AUSWI xmlns:aw="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bbk="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01 BbkXmwAuswi_2013.xsd" version="1.0" erstellzeit="2013-12-05T14:39:37" stufe="Produktion" xmlns="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01">
```

What can I do to change the order so that the `xmlns` attribute is the first one? It should be like this:

```
<LIEFERUNG-AUSWI xmlns="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01" xmlns:aw="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bbk="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01 BbkXmwAuswi_2013.xsd" version="1.0" erstellzeit="2013-12-05T14:39:37" stufe="Produktion">
```

This Question is the same but there was no answer:
[Write xmlns element with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077265/write-xmlns-element-with-attributes)

Comment: What is the significance in having xmlns come first?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result with the following code:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("LIEFERUNG-AUSWI", "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "aw", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "bbk", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", null, "https://www.bundesbank.de/Redaktion/DE/Downloads/Service/Meldewesen/Aussenwirtschaft/Vordrucke/xsd/bbkxmwauswi_2013.xsd?__blob=publicationFile");
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "version", null, "1.0");
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "erstellzeit", null, DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "stufe", null, "Produktion");
```

However, note that the `aw` namespace prefix refers to the same namespace as the  default namespace. They both refer to `"http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01"`. A fix would be to write the root element (`LIEFERUNG-AUSWI`) with the `aw´ prefix _or_ to remove the`aw` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 writer.WriteStartElement("LIEFERUNG-AUSWI");      
 writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01");

 ....

 writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "aw", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2013-01-01");
 writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
 writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "bbk", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01");
```

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work i got something different as output... I can try it again but i think it's not the right answer

Comment: This returns an XmlException. @Jan-PeterVos explains [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048695/xml-writeattributestring-error) that "you need to define the namespace of the element on the WriteStartElement itself." His answer corrects the exception, but doesn't solve the order issue.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a simple [answer with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77580300/2618319)  to a similar question, that shows how to control the order of the `xmlns` attribute by explicitly adding it as a regular `XAttribute` to an `XElement` (no custom `XmlWriter` implementation needed).